# Reading messages from multiple mailboxes using windows service

Tags: .net, windows-services, timer

I've a requirement to read mails from different POP mail servers using a windows service. Since I don't have much experience on windows services I'm looking for a good strategy to implement this. The mailbox server details and the credentials are stored in database and there may be hundred. The windows service should be designed in such a way it can read mails from 10 or more mail servers at a time (but there is limit).

I thought of using timer but I think it will create a new thread every-time (I'm not sure how timer really works) and I can't control the no. of threads running at a time but I've to limit the maximum no. of threads running at a time.

What is the better solution to apply here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of querying the database and then connecting to those mail servers and fetch mails is not different because you put it in a Windows Service. You can create a console application and put a Start method inside the main and from that method you call another one called DoWork.

Now inside DoWork you have all your logic or the calls to BL if you will.

Easy to debug and no installation required during development. Migration of this to a Win Service is almost trivial then.